# Require LUA files using a standard relative path approach - problems with: attempt to call global 'myfunc' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

I need to call a LUA function, defined in another my .lua file; from another. So, what I want is the classic C/C++ include approach.
I tried with the following:

```
(file funcs.lua)
function myfunc(arg1, arg2)
 ..dosomething
end
```

and

```
(file main.lua)
package.path = package.path .. ";/path/to/libs/?.lua"
require "funcs"
myfunc(1, 2)
```

The require works good, but at execution I get this error:

```
attempt to call global 'myfunc' (a nil value)
```

How come?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: What environment are you using for running Lua? At least with the vanilla command line interpreter, your sample works fine (given that the provided package path is correct).

Comment: How do you know that require is loading your file? I doubt it is, tbh...

Comment: I agree with previous comments: the code looks okay. However, you should change the way you think about it. `require` is not like `#include`. A Lua function definition is not like a C function declaration. In Lua, a function does not exist until its definition is run. Your `require` should be causing that. `funcs.lua` will create a global variable `myfunc` with an instance of the function. Put a breakpoint at the function definition to see if is being run. If breakpoints aren't available, use `assert` after your `require` and after `function myfunc...end`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for the comments; I'm running LUA under OpenResty/Nginx.

I solved by exporting directly the function(s), I don't know if this is the preferred method, but I noticed that is used by lots of newer LUA modules.
For example, I changed the code as follows:

```
file (funcs.lua)
local A = {}
function A.myfunc(arg1, arg2)
 ..dosomething
end
return A

(file main.lua)
package.path = package.path .. ";/path/to/libs/?.lua"
funcs = require "funcs"
funcs.myfunc(1, 2)
```

This works good and it's nice to have every function to be manually exported, in a sort of OOP-style.