# Lua require error if script is called "table.lua"?

Tags: lua, reserved-words

Trying to replicate [this simple Lua example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430230/require-lua-files-using-a-standard-relative-path-approach-problems-with-attem) (using the improved code in the **second** post), I encountered the following strange issue:

I copied the code verbatim, but happened to call the first file "*table.lua*" (instead of "*funcs.lua*"). 
The second file was called "*main.lua*" as in the example.

In my case, whatever I tried, I invariably got the popular error message "a*ttempt to call field 'myfunc' (a nil value)*" (as if the require statement had been ignored; but path etc. were all in order).

After two  hours of trying and hunting for info, I more or less on a hunch renamed the first file from "*table.lua*" to "*tabble.lua*", and then everything promptly worked as expected. Renaming to e.g. "*tables.lua*" will also work.

Being very new to Lua, I'd still like to understand what exactly went wrong. Initially I thought the reason might be that "*table*" is a reserved Lua word, but all references I checked do not list it as such.

So what is going on here?

I am using LuaForWindows v5.1.4-46 with the included SciTE editor/IDE (v.1.75).

Thanks for all hints.

Comment: It will be easier to help if you give the code you’re using in your own post, instead of through a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard libraries `math`, `io`, `string`, …, and `table` are pre-defined (and pre-loaded) in the Lua interpreter.  Because require caches modules by name, saying `require "table"` will return the standard `table` library instead of loading your own `table` module from a file.

A good way to solve the problem is to create a folder and put your library files in there.  If the folder is called `mylib`, then `require "mylib.table"` will work and load the file.

Alternatively, if you just need to load the file once and do not need the features of `require` (searching the file in a number of directories, caching loaded libraries), you can use [`loadfile`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-loadfile):  Change `require "table"` to `loadfile "./table.lua" ()` (where `./table.lua` should be the full (relative is fine) path to the file.)

Comment: That explains it indeed. Didn't think of the libraries, only of reserved words. (Upvote invisible due to my lack of street cred.)